# Python, CrossWord, Gui

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, crossword

I am very beginner on Python and I want to create crossworld template, like this. How can I create gui exactly like this on python ? Are there any tools or libraries ? I made lots of research but ı could not find anything.

Thanks!!!

[image]

Comment: How is your crossword puzzle program progressing?  Do you have it posted on GitHub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're a beginner, try out [PySimpleGUI](http://www.PySimpleGUI.org).

Here's a little program to get you started...

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
    import PySimpleGUI as sg
else:
    import PySimpleGUI27 as sg
import random

BOX_SIZE = 25

layout = [
            [sg.Text('Crossword Puzzle Using PySimpleGUI'), sg.Text('', key='_OUTPUT_')],
            [sg.Graph((800,800), (0,450), (450,0), key='_GRAPH_')],
            [sg.Button('Show'), sg.Button('Exit')]
         ]

window = sg.Window('Window Title').Layout(layout).Finalize()

g = window.FindElement('_GRAPH_')

for row in range(16):
    for i in range(16):
        if random.randint(0,100) > 10:
            g.DrawRectangle((i*BOX_SIZE+5,row*BOX_SIZE+3), (i*BOX_SIZE+BOX_SIZE+5,row*BOX_SIZE+BOX_SIZE+3), line_color='black')
        else:
            g.DrawRectangle((i*BOX_SIZE+5,row*BOX_SIZE+3), (i*BOX_SIZE+BOX_SIZE+5,row*BOX_SIZE+BOX_SIZE+3), line_color='black', fill_color='black')

        g.DrawText('{}'.format(row*6+i+1),(i*BOX_SIZE+10,row*BOX_SIZE+8))

while True:             # Event Loop
    event, values = window.Read()
    print(event, values)
    if event is None or event == 'Exit':
        break

window.Close()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it really helped. Is there way a making square editable ? Than you so much.

Comment: Post an Issue with new feature idea on the GitHub site http://www.PySimpleGUI.com.  Working on the ability to click on the squares right now, so yes is the answer to ability to "edit".

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: The code that returns back "clicks" on the canvas is done and checked in.  Look at sample program to see how it's used: https://github.com/MikeTheWatchGuy/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Crossword_Puzzle.py

Comment: Thank you very much, it gave me better understanding.